# Plugins for putting Custom Post Types into the Menu

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, menus

I have been building a website that has numerous `custom post types`, and I have found one called `WordPress Post Type Archive Links`. This would allow me to add a link to the an archive of registered `post types`. When you are on the archive pages, then the menu item is selected, however, when you go into a `taxonomy` (associated only with that `post type`), the menu is no longer marked as selected.

This isn't a major thing, but it makes the website loose some of its coolness. But, does anyone know how to modify that plugin, or a different plugin that would allow for me to put a link to a `custom post type` in the menu, that also remains selected when you are in the category view for that post type?

Comment: Search it up on GitHub (it's by @StephenHarris ) and open an issue there.

Comment: @kaiser just been having a look through, I can't find it, could you send me the link?

Comment: [Link to GitHub](https://github.com/stephenharris/WordPress-Post-Type-Archive-Links)

Comment: Noo, not the GitHub link, found that easily enough. I looked through the issues and couldn't see which one you were talking about

Comment: I said "open an issue". Haven't been saying anything about a specific already existing issue. If you're in doubt please read my first comment again.

Comment: Oop, my apologies, read that as there was an opened issue, soz man